# Check required for reverse geocoding

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I am coding an Android app, and I am trying to do reverse geocoding to show the current user's location on the map (by retrieving latitude and longitude of the user).

I am not getting the user's location at all, but other parts of the code are working, like adding markers.

Here is my main code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener,
        android.location.LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private Geocoder mGeocoder;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mSupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mGeocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (LocationListener) this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.normal:
                mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                break;
            case R.id.satellite:
                mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                break;
            case R.id.terrain:
                mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
                break;
            case R.id.hybrid:
                mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                break;
            case R.id.none:
                mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);

        showMyLocationOnScreen();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("I am here!");
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(options);
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        showMyLocationOnScreen();
    }

    private void showMyLocationOnScreen() {

        final LatLng PES_UNIVERSITY=new LatLng(12.9338,77.5345);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(PES_UNIVERSITY)
                .title("PES UNIVERSITY")
                .snippet("Banashankari,3rd stage,Bangalore")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));


        final LatLng PES_GYM = new LatLng(12.933996, 77.53438);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(PES_GYM)
                .title("PES GYM")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));

        final LatLng PES_CricketGround = new LatLng(12.93443, 77.533819);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(PES_CricketGround)
                .title("PES CRICKET GROUND")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

        final LatLng NesCafe = new LatLng(12.934913, 77.534608);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(NesCafe)
                .title("NESCAFE")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));

        final LatLng Chemistry_Lab = new LatLng(12.934801, 77.534702);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(Chemistry_Lab)
                .title("CHEMISTRY LAB")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET)));


        final LatLng CISCO = new LatLng(12.935496, 77.534723);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(CISCO)
                .title("CISCO")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));

        final LatLng CampusMart = new LatLng(12.935682, 77.534463);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(CampusMart)
                .title("CAMPUS MART")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));

        final LatLng CafeCoffeeDay = new LatLng(12.933591, 77.534636);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(CafeCoffeeDay)
                .title("CAFE COFFEE DAY")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));

        final LatLng BasketballCourt = new LatLng(12.933727, 77.534896);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(BasketballCourt)
                .title("BASKETBALL COURT")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

        final LatLng Pir_Cube = new LatLng(12.933696, 77.534601);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(Pir_Cube)
                .title("PIR CUBE")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE)));

        final LatLng Food_Court = new LatLng(12.933618, 77.534333);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(Food_Court)
                .title("FOOD COURT")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));

        final LatLng PES_Boys_Hostel = new LatLng(12.933276, 77.534935);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(PES_Boys_Hostel)
                .title("PES BOYS HOSTEL")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));

        final LatLng IT_Block = new LatLng(12.933278, 77.534423);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(IT_Block)
                .title("IT BLOCK")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

        final LatLng South_Canteen = new LatLng(12.934559, 77.535666);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(South_Canteen)
                .title("SOUTH CANTEEN")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));

        final LatLng MRD = new LatLng(12.9354, 77.534942);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(MRD)
                .title("MRD BLOCK")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

        final LatLng Panini_Block = new LatLng(12.932731, 77.534548);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(Panini_Block)
                .title("PANINI BLOCK")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

        final LatLng South_Mess = new LatLng(12.93321, 77.534903);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(South_Mess)
                .title("SOUTH MESS")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));


        final LatLng B_Block = new LatLng(12.935343, 77.534306);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(B_Block)
                .title("B BLOCK")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: Is it possible that your geocoder find my location call is returning prior to the map being ready?

Comment: Could anybody please help me in retrieving the current location

Comment: Can you respond to my previous comment? Also, it looks like the callback you're using is deprecated (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener)